# best_in_place & model attribute accessing (noob?)

Tags: nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, best-in-place

I've only been learning Rails for ~a month, so I'm not sure if the answer here is really simple or more complex.

I have two models, we will call them "SpecialUser" and "User".

My User model looks something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :special_user
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :roles, :user_type, :address_1, :address_2, :city, :state, :zip
```

(&c.)

And my SpecialUser model looks something like this:

```
class SpecialUser < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

(&c.)

We are using https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place to create a form to edit the information for the SpecialUser.  Previously, we had a separate "address" attribute for the SpecialUser, but recently pulled it in favor of specifying the full address (address_1, address_2, city, state, zip...) and putting that in the user so that regular users can have addresses too. :)

However, when I try to do this:

```
<% # best_in_place_if can?(:edit, @super_user), @super_user.user, :address_1 %>
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Project_professionals#show

undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000013457fb90>:0x00000132e1fdd8>
```

I have also tried replacing `@super_user.user` with `User.find(@super_user.user)` and `User.find(@super_user.user_id)`, but I get the exact same error.

When I do

```
<%= @super_user.user.address_1 %>
```

It works!

After reading through the best_in_place stuff, I'm still having trouble finding my answer.  :(  Not sure if it's a limitation of the gem we're using or me missing something.

Answer (score 0):

best_in_place should handle it -- no limitation

See if this fixes it

> :path: URL to which the updating action will be sent. If not defined
>   it defaults to the :object path.

```
<%= best_in_place_if can?(:edit, @super_user), @super_user.user, :address_1, :path => super_user_user_path %>
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you so much! :)  I actually had to use just `super_user_path` instead of `super_user_user_path` as the latter didn't exist.  Monkeyed around and found that the regular path worked just fine. :)


**EDIT**: So, I spoke a bit too soon.... it will display the data from the DB and when I click to edit it, the console log throws this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.  I'm going to keep fooling around with it, but can you think of anything off the top of your head that would make this go away? :)

Comment: ended up giving up on this and moving the address data into the super_user table and out of the user table.